# Calculating input impedance in a simple circuit

Tags: ac, input-impedance

I want to calculate the input impedance in the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKsuHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the leftmost loop I have that

$$U_{in}+I_{in}R=V_1$$

so it seems like I need to express V1 in terms of Uin, but I am unable to do that. How should I approach this problem?

Can I replace the driven current source with an equivalent voltage source in series with the resistor? And then add the two voltage sources which would then be in series?

Comment: Isn't V1 already in terms of Uin in the above equation? Input impedance will therefore be Uin/Iin or V1/Iin - R.

Comment: I need an additional equation to get an actual answer since U_in and I_in are a test source and a test current.

Comment: Clue: Since Z=V/I an ideal voltage source has an impedance of 0 ohm and an ideal current source has infinite impedance

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has a sign error.

Applying KCL at the \$U_{in}\$ node, see that the current through \$R\$ is from *right to left* which implies

$$U_{in} - I_{in} R = V_1$$

In fact, and more generally, recognize that the parallel resistor and controlled current source can be replaced with a resistor of resistance \$-R\$.

To see this, look at a similar pair in isolation driven by a current test source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fefJ3T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The test source "sees", in this case, a \$-1\Omega\$ resistance.

To find the input impedance, use a similar approach to find the equivalent impedance of the circuit to the *right* of the negative resistor and then you will have reduced the circuit to a simple circuit with two series impedances.  The input impedance will then be obvious.